# Unable to Navigate pages while keeping the tab bar accessible in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, navigationservice

So I have a tab bar and some pages attached to it, and what I'm trying to do is navigate to a different page(not a tab bar page) by clicking a button which is present in one of these tab bar pages, on doing so that page is replacing the tab bar, how would I be able to navigate inside the tab bar itself, I checked a couple of threads and doing a PushAsync should do the trick but its not working

This is a snippet of my NavigateAsync Method

```
  public async Task NavigateAsync(string pageKey, object[] parameter, bool animated = true)
    {
        var page = GetPage(pageKey, parameter);
        await CurrentNavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page, animated);
    }

  private readonly Stack<NavigationPage> _navigationPageStack = new Stack<NavigationPage>();

    private NavigationPage CurrentNavigationPage => _navigationPageStack.Peek();
```

Comment: Are you open to switch to [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs)

Comment: not right now, because might have to change a lot I suppose and would take some time for it ?

Comment: yes ive used popasync as well

Comment: @Cfun how can i use shell could you guide me through ??

Comment: each tab you wan to navigate within needs to contain a NavigationPage.  This will allow you to navigate within the current tab

Comment: tried that as well doesn't seem to work @Jason

Comment: there is not enough context in the code you posted to show what your page structure is or how your navigation works.  My guess is that you are using a NavigationPage that contains your TabbedPage, not the NavigationPage that is contained within your TabbedPage

Comment: try using `page.Navigation.PushAsync()` - this should use the NavigationPage that is attached to the current page

Comment: my tabbedpage is inside a navigationpage and set as the MainPage for the application and then, when i call NavigateAsync, as per my service it uses NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync() as seen in my code posted, let me know if you need anything more @Jason

Comment: wrapping the new page inside NavigationPage just creates one more Back Bar on top nothing else, i can share a screenshot

Comment: Your TabbedPage should be the root page of your application, not wrapped in a NavigationPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out in my navigation service, i was using the tabbedpage as a navigationpage to navigate to other pages, but if you get the current page (which should be encapsulated in a navigation while adding them as children to your tabbedpage), then using that if you navigate it creates a new page inside the current page instead of the whole tabbedpage

Here's my syntax for storing the currentPage as my navigation element to navigate

```
 public Page SetRootPage(string rootPageKey = null, Page pageName = null)
    {
        NavigationPage tempPage = null;
        if (rootPageKey != null)
        {
            var rootPage = GetPage(rootPageKey);
            if (rootPage is TabbedPage tabbedRootPage)
            {
                tempPage = tabbedRootPage.CurrentPage as NavigationPage;
            }
            if (tempPage == null)
            {
                CurrentNavigationPage = rootPage is NavigationPage ? (NavigationPage)rootPage : new NavigationPage(rootPage);
            }
            else 
            {
                CurrentNavigationPage = tempPage;
            }
            return CurrentNavigationPage;
            // as NavigationPage;
            //_navigationPageStack.Clear();
            //var mainPage = new NavigationPage(rootPage);
            // _navigationPageStack.Push(mainPage);
        }
        else
        {
            if (pageName is TabbedPage tabbedPage)
            {
                CurrentNavigationPage = tabbedPage.CurrentPage as NavigationPage;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentNavigationPage = pageName as NavigationPage;                    
            }
            return CurrentNavigationPage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a CurrentPage property in TabbedPage. You will need this CurrentPage.Navigation object to push the page inside tab bar itself.

Comment: yes this helped but my main page wasnt a tabbar but rather was a normal contentpage, so had to modify the service a bit